# CSS changes not reflecting on page

Tags: css

I'm setting up a uscreen website, but have problems adjusting the template font colors with css. I'm trying to change the color of the text "Unohditko salasanasi?" on this page: https://rawinto.uscreen.io/sign_in

This is the CSS I have added (copied from dev tools local changes):

```
.variant-text.color-primary[data-v-17fd35e2] {
    color: #1a202c !important;
}
```

I must be doing it wrong - new to css. Help please?

Comment: Can you please add your HTML code as well so we can help you better?

Comment: We can't debug this without a [mcve]

Comment: This was bit hard, since I'm restricted by the uscreen.io platform. But I got the code confirmed to be correct, it was just placed in the wrong section in the system (common pages have different CSS setup in Uscreen).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

CSS not getting reflected as browser it getting that file from cache.

You can solve this issue in 2 way.

1. Disable the Cache using dev tool.
2. Try Empty cache and [Hard Reload](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/help/how-to-clear-cache-and-hard-reload-browsers/).

Comment: Didn't help - I think the problem is with the CSS itself?

Comment: are you using css file ?

Comment: I've modified the hard reload link. please check that.

Comment: I've hard reloaded, no help. The CSS must be applied within a specific file in the uscreen system. I would just like to me sure I declared the font color change correctly?

Comment: can you please share html code for particular tag or element.

Answer (score 0):

The CSS code was correct, I got that confirmed. Should someone else stumble on this same problem in the future with Uscreen, I will paste the instructions from uscreen tech support here:

"When customizing your site using CSS, please make sure to create a backup and add your CSS inside the  of the theme.liquid file, the Common Pages CSS or the Head Code Snippet using  as well. It might be dangerous to edit the theme CSS as that is a minified CSS file and could break other parts of the site."

Answer (score -1):

Disable Cache in your browser and refresh. it should work

Comment: Didn't help - I think the problem is with the CSS itself?

Answer (score -1):

try deleting your cache and run page again
or open page in private window